# Mark edges in an image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, logic

I wrote a function to mark the edges of objects in pixel-level labeled images:

```
import numpy as np

def mark_edges(image, marker):

     axes = len(image.shape)
     edges = []

     for i in range(axes):
         shiftright = np.greater(image, np.roll(image, 1, axis=i))
         shiftleft = np.greater(image, np.roll(image, -1, axis=i))
         idx = np.where(shiftright != shiftleft)
         edges.append(idx)

     for idx in edges:
         image[idx] = marker

     return image
```

For isolated objects this works fine, since every label is greater than the background:

```
a = np.zeros(40).reshape(5,8)
a[1:4, 1:7] = 2
print(mark_edges(a, 99))

[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  99.  99.  99.  99.  99.  99.   0.]
 [  0.  99.   2.   2.   2.   2.  99.   0.]
 [  0.  99.  99.  99.  99.  99.  99.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

But if two differently labeled objects are next to each other the outcome is slightly different:

```
b = np.zeros(40).reshape(5,8)
b[1:4, 1:4] = 2
b[1:4, 4:7] = 4
print(mark_edges(b, 99))

[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  99.  99.  99.  99.  99.  99.   0.]
 [  0.  99.   2.   2.  99.   4.  99.   0.]
 [  0.  99.  99.  99.  99.  99.  99.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

Ideally there should be another marker at position (2,3). Do I have to accept this inaccuracy or is there a way around?

Comment: Hi ubik, I'm not sure I understand your expected output. Mind explaning a little bit more?

Comment: Hi RafaelC, I made an edit. I hope this clarifies it a little bit more.

Comment: Did you to look at the Sobel filter?: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.sobel.html, or If you want to do it by hand the convolution from `ndimage`  could be better to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `np.greater`, use `np.not_equal`. This will cause all regions to have their edges marked, including the background region.

Next, remove the edges over the background region.

In the code below, I use a "mask image" rather than a list of edge pixels. I find this easier to work with, and is quite efficient too.

```
import numpy as np

def mark_edges(image, marker):

  axes = len(image.shape)
  mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=bool)

  for i in range(axes):
    shiftright = np.not_equal(image, np.roll(image, 1, axis=i))
    shiftleft = np.not_equal(image, np.roll(image, -1, axis=i))
    mask |= shiftright != shiftleft

  mask[image==0] = 0
  image[mask] = marker

  return image
```

Output for image `b` from the question:

```
>>> b = np.zeros(40).reshape(5,8)
>>> b[1:4, 1:4] = 2
>>> b[1:4, 4:7] = 4
>>> print(mark_edges(b, 99))
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  99.  99.  99.  99.  99.  99.   0.]
 [  0.  99.   2.  99.  99.   4.  99.   0.]
 [  0.  99.  99.  99.  99.  99.  99.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

Comment: Your approach with the mask is great, but unfortunately there are now more marker-values than edges in the original. For array "a" two more edge-markers are introduced, which results in shrinkage of the interior region and for array "b" all entries with value 2 have been overwritten with the marker-value such that no interior region remains.

Comment: @ubik: I don't see this (see the edit). Remember that the function overwrites the input array (I would normally not write such a function but I wrote it like you did). Maybe you applied the function to the array as modified by your function? You need to re-create the input array for testing.